# Adding csrf_token to my post request from iPhone app

Tags: python, iphone, django, django-csrf

I have  an iPhone application from which I would like to call a post service passing parameters in its request, doing so caused a server error 500.

I have read Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/) and I still haven't figure out how to get a `csrf_token` and how to add it to the `AFNetworking AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST` method.

On the server side I've added `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` section, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

My view looks like this; I am not doing much, just hoping to pass.

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def foo(request):
   c={}
   c.update(csrf(request))
   if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponseRedirect("Post received");
```

Comment: do you have a `{% csrf_token %}` inside of your <form/> tags?

Comment: @TehTris I don't have any template so no form only urls.py models.py and views.py

Comment: whats the view def you are trying to view look like then? as far as i know `{% csrf_token %}` is required somewhere in the HTML rendering process ( like in the form ) if its yelling about csrf tokens

Comment: @TehTris i've updated the question with the view, I also understand that the token should be embedded in the request, that is why i'm asking how to get one, and how to add it in the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST

Answer (score 1):

The Django CSRF Middleware uses cookies and forms and whatnot to send a code to the page, then make sure the correct page is the one sending information back. In both cases, you must do a GET request to the server, and if you have the middleware installed correctly, it will put the CSRF token into a cookie for you.

Check out [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) for more info on this.

Now, I noticed you're using a library that uses NSURLConnection, so that should handle cookies for you. I got this bundle of code (untested) that lets you pull the cookie name that you specify in your settings file (again, check out the documentation link above) then put that in your POST.

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL: networkServerAddress];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) 
{
    // get the right cookie
}
```

Of course, if you're only making POSTs and never GETs first, you don't have a CSRF token to send!

And that's why we have the @csrf_exempt tag. ([Docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)) This is the way to go 99% of the time, since most apps you won't do a GET before you do a POST. (in webpages you have to do a GET first). Note that this is intended only when an app is sending only POSTs and there's no session to speak of. You really need to think about your own security when using this, and how you verify that a given app/user really is who they claim to be. And how you disable people from hitting this URL from a webbrowser.

**TLDR**: Probably use @csrf_exempt on the view, but be careful.

Comment: As I mentioned i read the documentation implemented the steps and it didn't work I even have a link to it in my question :) does each get returns a different csrf or it's the same one throughout the entire program?

Comment: I saw the documentation link, but the part I linked about AJAX explained specifically about how the cookie is set and what you need to do with it. Note the part about calling ensure_csrf_cookie(). Django sets the token on login, and I don't believe it does any time after that. How are you using these calls? Are there GET requests, or is it just POSTing to an API?

Comment: I'm not using AJAX, these are only API POST for my iPhone application